# VB script or Batch script to detect changes after autorefresh

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, alert

Can anyone help me with this?

I have VB script to auto refresh webpage every 20 seconds.

But i need one more feature.

i need alert message (messagebox or popup or just cmd prompt ) when there is a dfference between old webpage and autorefreshed webpage.

is it possible in VB or batch?

For autorefreshing i am using

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com"    ' change to actual site needed
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While True
    WScript.Sleep 10000    ' 10 seconds
    IE.Refresh()
Loop
```

From http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=23314.0

Answer (score 1):

You can get the html response text, make a hash, and store it somewhere at first. On each subsequent refresh, repeat the procedure and compare the hash for any changes.

Edited: As an alternative, you can try the following

```
Dim init
Dim temp
init = GetString()

Do While True
    WScript.Sleep 10000    ' 10 seconds
    temp = GetString()
    If temp <> init Then
    MsgBox "Not Equal"
    Else    
    MsgBox "Equal"
    End If
    init = temp
Loop

Function GetString()
    Dim o
    Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    o.open "GET", "http://www.example.com", False
    o.send
    GetString=o.responseText
End Function
```